# Execure oracle procedure using PetaPoco

Tags: c#, oracle, petapoco

We use Oracle DB. We need to execute the following stored procedure, which has worked when we executed it directly on DB.

```
exec DWHCR.LANCEKING_PA.FORWARD_WF_PR(12345, 'WF_T02', 'Test123');
```

We tried the following method from PetaPoc to execute the procedure:

```
            _dataBase.ExecuteNonQueryProc("DWHCR.LANCEKING_PA.FORWARD_WF_PR", new
            {
                P_ID_WF = 12345,
                P_RECEIVER = "WF_T02",
                P_COMMENT = "Test123"
            });
```

Unfortunately, we are getting the error

```
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException
ORA-01008: Nicht allen Variablen ist ein Wert zugeordnet
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.VerifyExecution(Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, SqlStatementType sqlStatementType, Int32 arrayBindCount, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)
```

Could anyone please help us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We needed put "begin" and "end" between the statement as shown below:

```
 _dataBase.Execute("begin DWHCR.LANCEKING_PA.FORWARD_WF_PR (1234, 'WF_T02', 'Test123'); end;");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the parameters:

```
_dataBase.ExecuteNonQueryProc(";DWHCR.LANCEKING_PA.FORWARD_WF_PR( @P_ID_WF, @P_RECEIVER, @P_COMMENT)", 
new {
            P_ID_WF = 12345,
            P_RECEIVER = "WF_T02",
            P_COMMENT = "Test123"
        });
```

or

```
_dataBase.ExecuteNonQueryProc(";DWHCR.LANCEKING_PA.FORWARD_WF_PR( @0, @1, @2)", 12345,"WF_T02", "Test123");
```

Not sure if you need the parenthesis between the parameters